# Splitting field of polynomial - how to factorise?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I'm looking for the splitting field of $x^5-4x+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know what to do once I have roots but I just can't work out how to get any roots for this polynomial! Any advice?

Comment: how to factorise what ?? what do you want to know about the splitting field ?

Comment: I need to find out what the splitting field is. I just can't find any way to split up my polynomial.